# tkinter python - Can I create window collision?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, collision, tkinter-canvas

New to programming. Working on a simple pong clone. Started the ball but want to make sure all sides of the window (500x500) will have the ball bounce off of it. How could I do this? Thanks!

P.S. This is my current code if needed.

```
import threading
import random
import time
import string
import os.path
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

class Pong:
    Title = 'Pong'
    Size = '500x500'

class Ball:
    def __init__(self,canvas,x1,y1,x2,y2):
        self.x1 =x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.ball = canvas.create_oval(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, fill="black")
    def move_ball(self):
        deltax = randint(0,5)
        deltay = randint(0,5)
        self.canvas.move(self.ball,deltax,deltay)
        self.canvas.after(50,self.move_ball)

def PongGame():
    print("Moved to PongGame.")
    ball1 = Ball(canvas,10,10,30,30)
    ball1.move_ball()

def titleButtonClicked(event):
    print("Title screen button clicked.")
    btn.pack_forget()
    btn.place(x=600,y=600)
    msg.pack_forget()
    PongGame()

root = Tk()
root.geometry(Pong.Size)
root.title(Pong.Title)
root.resizable(False,False)
msg = Label(root, text = Pong.Title, font = ("", 50))
msg.pack()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()
btn=Button(root, text = "Start")
btn.bind('<Button-1>', titleButtonClicked)
btn.place(x=220,y=300)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is a bit broad--there are a *lot* of ways to do it, so the general recommended approach is to pick one and try it. Then, when you run into a specific problem with your implementation, you can ask about that and it'll be on topic. See [ask] and good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I just need a simple collision that matches my resolution - 500 x 500. I'll be sure to check How to Ask. Once again, thanks!

Comment: You know the coordinates of the paddle and ball, and you know the coordinates of the edge of the screen. Just do the math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collisions are not trivial; the simplest is to reverse the `x` or the `y` velocity after checking which edge of the bounding box of the ball intersects with the boundaries of the canvas.

Maybe something like this:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500


class Ball:
    radius = 10
    spawn_center = (250, 100)

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = None
        self.create_ball()
        self.velocity = None
        self.assign_random_velocity()
        self.keep_moving = True
        self.move()

    def create_ball(self):
        xc, yc = self.spawn_center
        x0, y0, = xc - self.radius, yc + self.radius
        x1, y1, = xc + self.radius, yc - self.radius
        self.id = self.canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)

    def assign_random_velocity(self):
        dx = random.randrange(1, 5) * random.choice((1, -1))
        dy = random.randrange(1, 5) * random.choice((1, -1))
        self.velocity = (dx, dy)

    def move(self):
        if self.keep_moving is None:
            return
        self.check_collision()
        self.canvas.move(self.id, *self.velocity)
        self.keep_moving = self.canvas.after(10, self.move)

    def cancel_move(self):
        if self.keep_moving is not None:
            self.canvas.after_cancel(self.keep_moving)
        self.keep_moving = None

    def check_collision(self):
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        dx, dy = self.velocity
        if x0 < 0:
            x0 = 0
            dx = -dx
        elif x1 > WIDTH:
            x1 = WIDTH
            dx = -dx
        if y0 < 0:
            y0 = 0
            dy = -dy
        elif y1 > HEIGHT:
            y1 = HEIGHT
            dy = -dy   
        self.velocity = dx, dy


class PongBoard(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(self.master)
        self.ball = None
        self.spawn_new_ball()

    def spawn_new_ball(self):
        if self.ball is not None:
            self.ball.cancel_move()
            self.delete(self.ball.id)
        self.ball = Ball(self)


root = Tk()
root.geometry(f'{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT+20}')
board = PongBoard(root)
new_ball_btn = tk.Button(root, text='spawn new ball', command=board.spawn_new_ball)
board.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
new_ball_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This will get you started, but you will have to implement the paddles, the paddles movement, the collision checking of the ball with the paddles, and keep the score by yourself.